# Is the gom player and codec safe to download?

Tags: codec, gom-player

is the gom player and codec safe to download?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the one from [Gomlab](http://www.gomlab.com/eng/), yes. It's a nice player, it seeks well and it's small.

[VLC](http://videolan.org) still plays more file-types out of the box and tends to be the player I recommend as part of a coin flip with with [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html).

Comment: ya, highly recommend VLC player...+1